# How do you call a firestore function in functions shell?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore function defined as following:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('my_collection/{doc-id}')
  .onDelete((snapshot, _) => {
    const id = snapshot.id;
    // Do something with id
  })
```

I need to test this function and have resorted to `firebase functions:shell`, I can call `myFunction` like:

```
firebase> myFunction(/*What do I put in here?*/)
```

What arguments should I put in myFunction to get id === 'foo'? I've tried

```
firebase> myFunction({foo: ''})
```

but this doesn't seem to work as functions shell is assigning a random `'doc-id7'` to my id.

Comment: So you're saying you can't simply set the id property of the snapshot in the object you pass as the snapshot?

Comment: @DougStevenson the id property is implicit in the [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#id) and not actually a field in my document

Comment: So you didn't try to provide yourself with a custom QueryDocumentSnapshot object to process in the object you pass?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from @Doug Stevenson?

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you know how I can create a QueryDocumentSnapshot on Firebase Functions Shell? I'm not sure how I can access the DB on the Shell. The only documentation of the shell is https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell.

Comment: You can call the function with the id as following: myFirestoreFunction({id: ‘old’, foo: "somestuff"}). Please let me know if it worked. Here is [Firebase the Official Documentation for how to invoke Firestore Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_firestore_functions).